# Emacs: Disable a specific minor mode for all Lisp buffers

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, evil-mode, paredit

I want to avoid conflicts between [evil-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) and [paredit](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) by disabling the former for the buffers in which the latter is active.

The following code didn't work:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'turn-off-evil-mode)
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook 'turn-off-evil-mode)
(add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook 'turn-off-evil-mode)
(add-hook 'inferior-lisp-mode-hook 'turn-off-evil-mode)
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'turn-off-evil-mode)
(add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook 'turn-off-evil-mode)
(add-hook 'ielm-mode-hook 'turn-off-evil-mode)
(add-hook 'eval-expression-minibuffer-setup-hook 'turn-off-evil-mode)
```

In other words, how to auto-disable evil-mode for all Lisp buffers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just advice `paredit-mode`:

```
(defadvice paredit-mode (around paredit-disable-evil activate)
  (if paredit-mode
      ad-do-it
    (turn-off-evil-mode)
    ad-do-it))
```

Also, did you try [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy)?  It's my
Paredit-like package that's inspired by vi. It has more features than
Paredit, like inline-eval, region manipulation and outlines.

Comment: Lispy looks great! What features would I miss by replacing paredit-mode with lispy-mode? And how well can it coexist with evil-mode?

Comment: You will lose no features. But it takes a different approach: you have to be at-paren for doing things, while with Paredit you are allowed to be anywhere inside the list. I think it can work if you are in the insert mode of evil. Some adaptation may be required.

Comment: A nice intro that I just published: http://oremacs.com/2015/01/19/lispy.0.21.0-is-out/